# "position:sticky" does not work if contained in a parent

Tags: css, reactjs

I am implementing a `pull to refresh` ([this is the library](https://github.com/echoulen/react-pull-to-refresh) ), and it works fine in my code.  I'm trying to make each item in my array contained in `state.items` have `position:sticky` so that it is positioned at the top of the screen while scrolling.

The problem is that if I combine my `<PullToRefresh>` component, `position:sticky` doesn't work anymore, but if I comment out the whole `<PullToRefresh>`  component works fine.

this is my live code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-voice-1k3mt

(`<PullToRefresh>` is commented, `position:sticky` is working, but if but if I uncomment `<PullToRefresh>` the `position:sticky` will not work.):

```
  <>
    {/*<PullToRefresh
      pullDownContent={<div>Pulling</div>}
      releaseContent={<div>Releasing...</div>}
      refreshContent={<div>Refreshing...</div>}
      pullDownThreshold={0}
      onRefresh={async () => {
        this.addData();
      }}
      triggerHeight={600}
      backgroundColor={"white"}
      startInvisible={true}
    >*/}
    {this.state.items.map((title, i) => {
      return <h4 className="title">title {i}</h4>;
    })}
    {/*</PullToRefresh>*/}
  </>
```

How can I fix it so that I can have the `<PullToRefresh>` component and inside the titles with sticky position? or what alternative can I do to make my code work?

Comment: display:inline to pullToRefresh ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I am honored to hear from you.  I tried to do what you tell me, but then the pull to refresh stopped working (no more texts are displayed when I pull my content down). Here is my live code, if you could give me a hand I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: The two wrapping `div`s that `PullToRefresh` creates have `overflow: hidden`. This is maybe needed for it to function properly? If not, find a way to remove it.

Comment: @sallf I tried, but the pull to refresh is damaged :( . my knowledge is not enough to fix my problem, I hope you can help me, I know I will learn a lot.